# Turning an unneeded outlet into a light switch to power LED lights

Tags: electrical, switch, light

I would like to turn an outlet into a light switch to control I light fixture at another outlet in the wall at another location. I already installed the new outlet (that I'd like to have power when I turn on my new light switch) and ran new cable from this location to the socket I'd like to turn into a switch. Hope that doesn't sound too confusing.

My question has to do with the wiring. I already fished my wiring through the necessary spaces and I just need to know how to connect it all correctly. Would I disconnect the wiring at the outlet and then use that as my power source and wire it in this way I outlined below?

Turn power off at circuit breaker panel first, of course.

Black - hot from power source to light switch
Black - from cable leading to electrical box to light switch.

White - neutral from power source to white cable connecting to electrical box

Green/ground to green/ground

Answer (score 1):

Your plan sounds good the only problem is many receptacles are located is required spaces (habitable rooms no space more than 6’ from a receptacle 12 between them) so with that in mind if new receptacle is vertically the same or close there might not be any issues.